# firefox javascript compatibility

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, ibm-midrange

i have a table with some javascript

```
<td nowrap="" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(211, 211, 211);" onmouseout="this.style.background='#d3d3d3'; menu3.style.color='#000000'" onmouseover="this.style.background='#EE0000'; menu3.style.color='#ffffff'" onclick="javascript:validationMenu('010','006')">
    <span id="menu3" class="bulle" name="menu3" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
        Vue générale
    </span>
</td>
```

i have a problem with the onclick function validationMenu :

> function validationMenu(menu,option) {
>
> document.SCREEN.elements['l1_F010$NUOPTIA'].value =
>   trim(option.substring(1,4));
>     document.SCREEN.elements['l1_F010$NUMENUA'].value = trim(menu);
>     validateAndSubmit('ENTER');
>
> }

As we use the webfacing tool (ibm) the document.screen is used by the tool to map with iseries DDS screens

Using internet explorer it works fine but in firefox the console showing the warnings :

> TypeError: document.SCREEN is undefined 
>   TypeError: window.event is undefined

Comment: Where have you defined `document.SCREEN`?

Comment: Try [some background reading](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

Comment: `window.screen` ? I have never heard of `document.SCREEN`

Comment: i am sorry i have totally forgot to add some tags to the question & more details

Answer (score 0):

`document.SCREEN` may possibly be a proprietary JS object in IE, but it doesn't exist in FireFox.  It looks to me like you're using it to reference page elements, in which case you're safest using `document.getElementById('nameYourElement').value`.  Your element name will be the id attribute of the HTML tag.  To make it easier to work with you may consider JQuery, which will allow you to use `$('#nameYourElement').val()`.  You can then use any CSS selector including tags, classes, and pseudo-selectors.

Comment: The problem here is trying to make a webfacing generated app to work using firefox. the document.SCREEN is an object instantiated by the tool to capturate the DDS screen in iseries. The scenario here is user clicks on the td object the javascript code fills up the object screen with the command and sends it to iseries for processing via http post

Comment: Luckily I'm familiar with iSeries development, but I only really develop PHP to run on Zendserver and do not know RPG.  As far as DDS are you referring to table specs?  It sounds to me as if you're trying to reference fields in your 5250 session from a web browser, is that correct?  As a Linux user who develops on iSeries I know how tricky this can be, as IBM really supports Microsoft and everyone else seems to be in the dark.

Comment: Now that I'm read up on the webfacing tool, which seems to replace the 5250, is this basically 2 tabs you're trying to communicate between?  If so you'll need to find how to reference the other tab through Javascript, which may include custom coding.  Have you tried this in any other browsers?  (Chrome, Safari, Opera)

Comment: Thanks for your answer MaKR. it doesn't work inside any of the other browsers and according to the ibm docs, webfacing (with websphere v7) supports only ie and firefox starting version 2. The full application is based 5250 session after transforming it to a WAR hosted in WAS the firefox works for all screens except the dropdown list that doesnt work properly - i can add some custom javascript but i can't figure how come that the object document.screen wich is supposed to contain information about the 5250 DDS screen (handle user input) is undefined. is there any workaround ?

Comment: I don't know of one.  You might try Zend forums because they have a section dedicated to iSeries development, but it's PHP on Apache so I'm not sure how relevant.  Feel free to jump in on this thread too, which is also regarding linking web to a 5250 although it's through a different method: http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=77&t=118503

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does not have a global event object like IE and this is causing the webfacing script to not be loaded.

Firefox passes the event object as a parameter to the event handler so you *may* be able to work around the issue by replacing every reference to `window.event` in the webfacing script with `(arguments[0] || window.event)`.

---

Change references to `window.event.srcElement` to the following:

```
(arguments[0].target || window.event.srcElement)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i will try this soon and get back at you

Comment: After doing the modification i dont receive that error in the console anymore but i have another error showing up :  TypeError: document.SCREEN is undefined  and 
TypeError: (intermediate value).srcElement is undefined

Comment: @hamzahir Internet Explorer has a `srcElement` property that is named `target` in all other browsers.  I have updated the answer with an additional fix for that property.

Comment: thanks for your respond i have tried it and the only error still showing is : TypeError: document.SCREEN is undefined